# SystemVerilog Module, why does reset not reset

Tags: system-verilog

I am coding a SystemVerilog module that stores data in 2 memories for Matrix Vector Multiplication. I am running a provided testbench from my prof but I have been stuch trying to debug a memory address logic that simply does not reset to zero! Any ideas or suggestions are much appreciated.

Waveforms:
[waveforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocigW.png)

Module Code:

```
module input_mems #(
 parameter INW=4,
 parameter M=4,
 parameter N=4,
 localparam LOGN = $clog2(N),
 localparam LOGMN = $clog2(M*N)
 )(
 input clk, reset,

 input [INW-1:0] AXIS_TDATA,
 input AXIS_TVALID,
 input AXIS_TLAST,
 input [LOGN:0] AXIS_TUSER,
 output logic AXIS_TREADY,
 output logic input_loaded,
 input done,
 output logic [LOGN-1:0] D,
 input [LOGN-1:0] vector_read_addr,
 output logic [INW-1:0] vector_val,
 output logic [LOGN-1:0] vector_row,
 input [LOGMN-1:0] matrix_read_addr,
 output logic [INW-1:0] matrix_data
 );
   enum {RESET, INM, INV, INL} state, next_state;
   logic [LOGMN-1:0] matrix_addr;
   logic matrix_wr_en;
   logic [LOGN-1:0] vector_addr;
   logic vector_wr_en;
   logic matrix_loaded;
   logic vector_loaded;
   logic new_matrix;
   assign new_matrix = AXIS_TUSER[0];
   logic INM_skip;
   logic [$clog2(N)-1:0] row;
   assign row = AXIS_TUSER[$clog2(N):1];
   logic [INW+$clog2(N)-1:0] vector_cat_in;
   logic [INW+$clog2(N)-1:0] vector_cat_out;
   logic data_ready_INM;
   logic data_ready_INV;

   //fsm 
   //output logic
   always_comb begin
      if(state == RESET) begin
         AXIS_TREADY = 0;
         input_loaded = 0;
      end
      else if(state == INM) begin
         AXIS_TREADY = 1;
         input_loaded = 0;
      end
      else if(state == INV) begin
         AXIS_TREADY = 1;
         input_loaded = 0;
      end
      else if(state == INL) begin
         input_loaded = 1;
         AXIS_TREADY = 0;
      end
      else begin
         AXIS_TREADY = 0;
         input_loaded = 0;
      end
   end

   //next state logic
   always_comb begin
      if((state == RESET) && (reset == 1)) //stay in reset state
         next_state = RESET;
      else if((state == RESET) && (reset == 0)) //exit reset state
         next_state = INM;
      else if((state == INM) && (matrix_loaded == 1)) //matrix is loaded
         next_state = INV;
      else if((state == INM) && (INM_skip == 1)) //new_matrix says reuse matrix
         next_state = INV;
      else if((state == INM) && (matrix_loaded == 0)) //matrix not loaded yet
         next_state = INM;
      else if((state == INV) && (vector_loaded == 1)) //TLAST asserted
         next_state = INL;
      else if((state == INV) && (vector_loaded == 0)) //vector not loaded yet
         next_state = INV;
      else if((state == INL) && (done == 1)) //go back to beginning
         next_state = INM;
      else if((state == INL) && (done == 0)) //data not loaded yet
         next_state = INL;
   end

   //state register
   always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      if(reset == 1)
         state <= RESET;
      else
         state <= next_state;
   end


   //memory reset
   always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      if (reset == 1) begin
         matrix_addr <= 0;
         vector_addr <= 0;
         D <= 0;  //reset D counter
      end 
      else if (state == INL && next_state == INM) begin
         matrix_addr <= 0;
         vector_addr <= 0;
         D <= 0;
     end
   end

   //Matrix memory
memory #(
   .WIDTH(INW),
   .SIZE(M*N)
   )memory_matrix(
   .data_in(AXIS_TDATA),
   .data_out(matrix_data),
   .clk(clk),
   .addr(matrix_addr),
   .wr_en(matrix_wr_en));

   //Vector memory
memory#(
   .WIDTH(INW+$clog2(N)),
   .SIZE(N)
   )memory_vector(
   .data_in(vector_cat_in),
   .data_out(vector_cat_out),
   .clk(clk),
   .addr(vector_addr),
   .wr_en(vector_wr_en));

   //Matrix
   //wr_en signal
   always_comb begin
      if((AXIS_TREADY == 1) && (AXIS_TVALID == 1) && (state == INM))
         matrix_wr_en = 1;
      else
         matrix_wr_en = 0;
   end

   //Matrix address
   always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      if(matrix_wr_en == 1)
         matrix_addr <= matrix_addr + 1;
      else
         matrix_addr <= matrix_addr;
   end

   //Matrix loaded check
   always_comb begin
      if(reset == 1)
         matrix_loaded = 0;
      else if(matrix_addr == $clog2(M*N)) //we have written to all addresses
         matrix_loaded = 1;
      else
         matrix_loaded = 0;
   end

   //new_matrix check
   always_comb begin
      if((AXIS_TREADY == 1) && (AXIS_TVALID == 1) && (state == INM) && (matrix_addr == 0) && (new_matrix == 0))
         INM_skip = 1;
      else
         INM_skip = 0;
   end

   //Vector
   //wr_en signal
   always_comb begin
      if((AXIS_TREADY == 1) && (AXIS_TVALID == 1) && (state == INV))
         vector_wr_en = 1;
      else
         vector_wr_en = 0;
   end

   //Vector address
   always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      if(reset == 1)
         vector_addr <= 0;
      else if(vector_wr_en == 1)
         vector_addr <= vector_addr + 1;
      else
         vector_addr <= vector_addr;
   end
 
   //Vector loaded check
   always_comb begin
      if(reset == 1)
         vector_loaded = 0;
      else if(AXIS_TLAST == 1) //TLAST signal
         vector_loaded = 1;
      else
         vector_loaded = 0;
   end

   //Vector Data Concat.
   always_comb begin
      vector_cat_in = {AXIS_TDATA, row};
   end

   //D Counter
   always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      if(reset == 1)
         D <= 0;
      else if((AXIS_TREADY == 1) && (AXIS_TVALID == 1) && (state == INV) && (AXIS_TDATA != 0))
         D <= D + 1;
      else
         D <= D;
   end

   //Loaded
   //Matrix Read
   always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      if(input_loaded == 1)
         matrix_addr <= matrix_read_addr;
      else
         matrix_addr <= matrix_addr;
   end

   //Vector Read
   always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      if(input_loaded == 1) begin
         vector_addr <= vector_read_addr;
         vector_val <= vector_cat_out[INW+$clog2(N)-1:$clog2(N)]; // Select INW upper bits
         vector_row <= vector_cat_out[$clog2(N)-1:0]; // Select $clog2(N) lower bits
      end
      else
         vector_addr <= vector_addr;
   end

endmodule
```

Don't pay too much attention to what is happening with the data, I just cannot figure out why my reset will not set my matrix_addr to zero.

Comment: Downvote because the code is not minimal. Debugging is an important skill, creating a minimal example might have shown you where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple drivers on matrix_addr

This process

```
   //memory reset
   always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      if (reset == 1) begin
         matrix_addr <= 0;
         vector_addr <= 0;
         D <= 0;  //reset D counter
      end 
      else if (state == INL && next_state == INM) begin
         matrix_addr <= 0;
         vector_addr <= 0;
         D <= 0;
     end
   end
```

this process

```
   //Matrix address
   always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      if(matrix_wr_en == 1)
         matrix_addr <= matrix_addr + 1;
      else
         matrix_addr <= matrix_addr;
   end
```

and this process

```
   //Matrix Read
   always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      if(input_loaded == 1)
         matrix_addr <= matrix_read_addr;
      else
         // *** this else is not needed, this is a flip flop it holds its value ***
         matrix_addr <= matrix_addr;
   end
```

all drive matrix_addr.

SystemVerilog allows only one process or continuous assignment driver per variable within a scope.  None of the behavior modeled in the individual processes (like reset) will operate as expected.  Multiples drivers is why you are seeing x in the waves.

In SystemVerilog hardware is modeled.  Multiple drivers in the code is like connecting the outputs of multiple physical logic gates together in a hardware design.  This produces a short circuit in hardware, where one output is pulling up to the positive voltage rail and the other is pulling down to ground.  Its connecting Vcc to ground inside the logic gates which is a short circuit and will damage the physical gate.

There are several compile errors while using the Cadence, Synopsys, and Aldec simulation tools on EDA Playground. Only Mentor (Questa, [related to Modelsim]) compiles.
They look like this:

```
xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,124|11): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable matrix_addr detected.
```

The solution is to combine logic from multiple processes into one using if/else, case or other SystemVerilog statements.

Test the idea that multiple drivers is the issue by keeping the `// memory reset` process and commenting the `//Matrix address` process and the `//Matrix Read` process.  With the two processes commented, asserting the the reset input should reset matrix_addr, when clock and reset are correctly applied to the DUT.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I will likely rewrite the design to ensure I am not driving a variable from multiple sources. 
I guess questasim does not show errors indicating this and will successively compile.